# How can I enable sftp-4 or higher on ubuntu 14.04 or above?

Tags: permissions, ssh, sftp, ownership

I'd like to use sftp4 or higher. How can I do that?

Currently, I have openssh-server (OpenSSH_6.6.1p1) installed on Ubuntu 14.04 (old test server). I will upgrade, so answers for newer ubuntu server versions are welcomed.

Based on the error message below it would appear that I'm currently using sftp-3
[image: sftp-3 error message on ubuntu 14.04 using winscp]

I've tried to research which versions of openssh-server use sftp-4 or greater, but I've found next to no results. Can anyone help me? Which versions of openssh use sftp-4? Do any of the newer versions of Ubuntu server run sftp-4 or greater? If I can't do it using openssh-server, what alternatives do I have?

The reason for my question stems from the fact that I would like to change file permissions and ownership remotely using WinSCP. To do that, [I need to use sftp4 or higher](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/protocols) (actually that isn't quite true, apparently I can do it from sftp2 and above provided I use GID/UID, unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work.) Incidentally, I've sftp-6 as my preferred version in WinSCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSH supports SFTP version 3 only.

You would have to use a different SFTP server, such as [ProFTPD `mod_sftp`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html).